# Oz Installation Problems

Tags: oz, mozart

I'm having to install Oz on my computer for a class. I have Windows 10. I have already installed emacs and it runs fine. However, when I try to to install Oz (the latest version from Sourceforge) it gives me an error "CoCreateInstance failed". No one I've asked seems to know why and I can't find anything about it online. Any ideas or help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had to install older version until the 1.3.2 worked, I'm also using windows 10.

(If your class is going to use the CTM book as reference you should use the 1.3.0 btw)